# Alternative solution instead using the URLConnection in android

Tags: android

I think the `URLConnection` in android has a bug. Really I do not know. Please see the following code. this is very strange for me. I send from server the `hello` stream and when the android gets the `hello` stream and first it puts the `hello` stream in the `textView` but it can not run the true condition in the code, given that the `hello` stream in `php` is equal to `hello` stream in `android` code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
GetText();
    }
void GetText(){
    String text = "";
    BufferedReader reader=null;

    try
    {

        // Defined URL  where to send data
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/request.php");

        // Send POST data request

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();


        // Get the server response

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


        text = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

    // Show response on activity
    textView.setText( text  );
if(text.equals("hello"))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Yes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Solving this problem is very important for me. I should do difference operations based the data that they are sent from  `php` file. But my code runs the operations incomplete.

```
    // Show response on activity
        textView.setText( text  );//My code can set the text from php in the textView.
    if(text.equals("hello"))
    //My code can not display the `Yes` stream although the contents of the text variable is equal to the `hello` stream.     
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Yes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    My code displays the `No` stream and it is very strange for me.
    else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "
No",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Really there is not a solution or a alternative solution for me?

```
<?php

echo "hello";
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried it using `text.trim().equals("hello")`? There is a `\n` you are appending while reading from stream.

Comment: Even when I remove the `\n` and I use the `text.trim().equals("hello")`, there is this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parm1", params[0]));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
    String output;
    StringBuilder responseJsonStr = new StringBuilder();


    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        responseJsonStr.append(output);
    }
    if(!StringUtils.startsWith(responseJsonStr.toString(), "[")) {
        responseJsonStr.insert(0,"[");
        responseJsonStr.append("]");
    }
```

Comment: Your solution (`HttpClient`) is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of my problem. I changed my `php` file from the `Encoding:UTF-8` to the `Encoding:ANSI` and now I can run my code well.